# Can't connect remote to Apple TV after factory reset

Tags: appletv

I lost the remote for my 3rd generation Apple TV, so I ordered a new one from ebay. I've been unable to connect the new remote to the Apple TV. I've tried everything on Apple's website to do, with no luck. Finally, I found a YouTube video on how to "program your All in One remote" and that worked perfect, but now the Apple TV keeps asking me to put the password in for an incorrect Apple ID username.

With this new issue, I tried everything to change the Apple ID, and finally decided to try a complete factory reset. Now I can't get into settings to pair my iPhone 6. Since I did the reset I lost my remote's connection as well and now, with the iPhone not connecting to the Apple TV, I have no way to toggle around in the Apple TV screen to program the remote again (the way I connected it before). I've tried connecting the Apple TV directly via ethernet to my router, but the problem remains—**how can I pair a new remote to the Apple TV if I don't have a working remote and the Apple TV won't pair via Bluetooth with the Remote app on my iPhone 6?**

Comment: Turn on the AppleTV and let it power fully up to display the main menu. Then take the new remote and hold it where it is visible to the AppleTV box. Press and hold the Menu and Right buttons (i.e. the right-most button in the circle). After about 5 seconds the TV should show that the new remote has been linked to the AppleTV.